# LocalDate (de)serialization works in JAX-RS server but not JAX-RX client

Tags: java, serialization, jax-rs, localdate

I have a JAX-RS application running on WildFly and using RestEasy and Jackson for REST API and JSON processing. I am trying to serialize and deserialize LocalDate as ISO formatted strings. One way to do it is to use annotations to define serialization and deserialization methods as follows.

```
public class MyClassWithLocalDate{

    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate date;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    // constructor, getters and setters
}
```

My LocalDateSerializer is written by the book to create an output date in the ISO format. This works fine in a deployed application:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/localdate")
public Response getLocalDate() {
    MyClassWithLocalDate result = new MyClassWithLocalDate();
    result.setDate(LocalDate.now());
    result.setAmount(BigDecimal.TEN);
    return Response.ok().entity(result).build();
}
```

The code above uses class LocalDateSerializer to serialize LocalDate values resulting in compact JSON `{"date":"2018-07-11", "amount":10}`. However, I would like to create a test for the API by creating a deployment with Arquillian and then accessing the APIs using RestEasy client in the following manner:

```
@Test
@RunAsClient
public void testLocalDate() throws Exception {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    MyClassWithLocalDate myClass = new DistributionDate();
    myClass.setDate(LocalDate.now());
    myClass.setAmount(BigDecimal.ONE);
    WebTarget targetCreate = client.target("http://localhost:8080/test/localdate"));
    Response response = targetCreate.request().post(Entity.json(myClass));
```

This test is using same code base and, in particular, same MyClassWithLocalDate as the deployed application. However, when myClass is serialized in `post(Entity.json(myClass))` it does not use LocalDateSerializer but the default extremely verbose LocalDate serializer resulting in JSON `{"date":{"year":2018, "month":"JULY", "dayOfMonth":11, "dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY", "era":"CE", "dayOfYear":192, "leapYear":false, "monthValue":7, "chronology":{"id":"ISO", "calendarType":"iso8601"}}, "amount":10}`. How can I make the test class use LocalDateSerializer to serialize LocalDate when making the post? The annotation obviously was not enough.